# Only translate one module in Android

Tags: android

What's the best approach to only translate one module in Android?

I have added the translation for the language and in the module that I want the translation I override `attachBaseContext` to get the translations.

```
override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
```

But then in run-time when you refer to a string from a non-translated module that's define both in the translated module and non-translated module it will also find the translated string and thus, translate it.

Is the best approach to have different names on the strings? Or override `attachBaseContext` everywhere?

Comment: What does the "module" means? Do you want to translate only one activity? When should the languages change: on click the button inside your app or when you choose new device locale?

Comment: one module in the project, as an own library but included in the apk